# Progress Dialog canceled before the task finished on another AsyncTask

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I want to download stock from web using Web Service. Created Sync to delete current stock

```
new ResetStock().execute();
```

Here is ResetStock Async:

```
private class  ResetStock extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{ 
    ProgressDialog pd;



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.cancel();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pd=new ProgressDialog(FrmMainMenu.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait. We are Downloading the Catalogue...");
        pd.show();
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseHandlerStock dbc=new                        DatabaseHandlerStock(FrmMainMenu.this);
        dbc.deleteallstock();
        dbc.close();
        new AsyncStock(FrmMainMenu.this).execute();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now I Called Another Async to download and xml and insert into my database

here is Asyncstock

```
         List<Stock> mystocks = null;
     Context mcontext;

int x=0;
public AsyncStock(Context context) {
    super();
    this.mcontext = context;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        URLConnection conn = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/mob2server.asmx/GetStock").openConnection();

        mystocks = SAXXMLParser.parse(conn.getInputStream());

     DatabaseHandlerStock dbc;
     dbc=new DatabaseHandlerStock(mcontext);
     String  category,  make,  model, productcode,  productname,  smallimages, largeimages,  description,  mrp,  unit, pkg;
     for(Stock in :mystocks)

        {
         x++;
            category=in.getCategory();
            make=in.getMake();
            model=in.getModel();
            productcode=in.getProductcode();
            productname=in.getProductname();
            smallimages=in.getSmallimages();
            largeimages=in.getLargeimages();
            description=in.getDescription();
            mrp=in.getMrp();
            unit=in.getUnit();
            pkg=in.getPkg();

            dbc.addContact(new Catalogue(category.replace("$","&"),  make.replace("$","&"),  model.replace("$","&"), productcode,  productname.replace("$","&"),  smallimages, largeimages,  description.replace("$","&"),  mrp,  unit, pkg));
        }
    dbc.close();
      }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

     Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Total " + x + " Models Imported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onPostExecute(result);


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();
}

}
```

My First dialog is cancel before the stock is inserted into stock.
I want my dialog to be there until stock is inserted into my database.

Comment: doinbackground is invoked on the background thread. You need to invoke asynctask on the ui thread. `execute(Params...)` must be invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: write this line pd.dismiss() in onpost exuecute method

Comment: call your second Asyntask in post execute of first asyntask and take one progress dialog instance and dismiss it in postexecute of second asyntask

Comment: Thanks It worked me. Called both ASYNC on button click new ResetStock().execute();
     new AsyncStock(FrmMainMenu.this).execute();

Answer (score 0):

Create another class and pack your second asynctask stuff in it. You can than call this new class in your first asynctask. Also use the progress update to see what is going on. In this way you will have only one progress bar but will keep you informed.